# Prevent an object from being converted to a reactive Object when assigned to a component property

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component

This one is a bit weird, sorry.

I am using a third party library to get some data from an API

```
import lib from 'third-party'
import Vue from 'vue'

@Component({})
export default UserComponent extends Vue{
  public user = null as lib.User | null

  mounted(){
    lib.getUser().then((val: lib.User) => {
      this.user = val; /// this is where things blow up
    })
  }
} // this is from memory, but it looks like a decent recreation ¯\_(ツ)_/¯
```

So the lib takes the response form the API call and uses it to generate an instance of type `lib.User`.  It is fine up to this point, but as soon as I assign the response to a property in my component several functions in the new 'lib.User' instance fire and I start getting a good number of errors.

My guess is Vue is converting the objects properties to reactive properties and this is causing events to fire.

I would like to have this object in the component and not have to map it to a locally generated object, if I could avoid it.

Is there anyway to prevent this behavior?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming that the cause of your problem is due to the object being made reactive, then you can avoid this from happening in 3 ways.

**Way 1**

Do not define `user` as a reactive data property on the component instance. I'm not sure how to do this in Typescript, but typically you would omit `user` from the data object and instead initialize `this.user` in the `created` hook instead.

A consequence of this is that the `this.user` property will not be reactive. This probably isn't what you want.

**Way 2**

If you assign frozen objects to `this.user` then Vue will not make the object reactive:

```js
this.user = Object.freeze(user)
```

A consequence of this is that all properties on the `user` object will become readonly, which probably isn't what you want.

You may be able to use `Object.seal()` or `Object.preventExtensions()` instead.

**Way 3**

You can trick Vue into thinking that the `user` object is already reactive by assigning a `_isVue` property on it to true; that way Vue won't observe it.

```js
user._isVue = true
this.user = user
```

A consequence of this is that it is not a public API (as far as I know) so it may change in the future (and I assume it probably will come Vue 3).

Comment: This looks very promising.  Truth is I think user being readonly is fine.  I will try this later and mark accordingly .  Thanks a ton.